# How to set interceptors based on the rpc methods

Tags: go, grpc

I have a requirement where i don't want to execute interceptors for all the rpc methods, How i can set the interceptors conditionally?
looking for something similarly.
https://chenyitian.gitbooks.io/gin-tutorials/content/tdd/21.html
execute interceptors for few routes

Answer (score 0):

The interceptors all have access to the RPC method string (in the format of `/package.service/method`).
https://github.com/grpc/grpc-go/blob/master/interceptor.go#L43

You can check the method string before executing the interceptor body.

Comment: i need to write the if else case in the interceptor, instead of that can i group methods based on the interceptor, same way we can group the middleware in gin . https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42373423/how-to-add-multiple-groups-to-gin-routing-for-api-version-inheritance